# Simple GitHub Actions workflow doesn't start

Tags: github, github-actions

I just wanted to test GitHub's new "GitHub Actions" feature. So I created a `.github` folder in my repository and a `workflows` folder within that and added a simple `test-workflow.yml` to that folder:

```
name: Hello World

#on:
#  schedule:
#    #- cron:  '0 */12 * * *'
#    - cron:  '* * * * *'

on: [push]

jobs:
  one:
    name: Hello
    runs-on: alpine-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "hello world"
```

But it doesn't appear to ever start. It just says "Starting your workflow run..." forever.

[image: screenshot]

I'm wondering what I might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your job is configured to run in an `alpine-latest` environment, but [GitHib doesn't provide `alpine-latest` as one of their workflow environments](https://help.github.com/en/articles/virtual-environments-for-github-actions). Your choices are `ubuntu-latest`, `macOS-latest`, `windows-latest`, or a specific version of one of those three OSes. Change `runs-on: alpine-latest` to `runs-on: ubuntu-latest` and your workflow should start.

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't answer the specific OP question, search engines bring us here, looking for the answer to why one's pipeline is stuck on "Starting your workflow run..."

If you are running your runner in a container, the chances are, Github has released a new version of the runner and your container is trying to update itself.
You can check the below URL to see when Github released the latest version:
https://github.com/actions/runner/releases

There are a lot of requests for Github to provide a feature to stop automatic updates, but to date (17/11/2020) they refuse to do so, claiming they need the auto-update functionality to support new features.

The suggested workaround is to develop a build pipeline for your container that builds automatically when they push a new release.